# How to add multiple DataFlow tasks to a Foreach container

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ezapi

How to add multiple data flow tasks to a single `foreach` container using `EzAPI`. Basicly I need to do as following.

[image]

I am new to EzAPI. Can anyone give me a code sample for this kind of scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears you have already added multiple dataflows to your for-each, so what is the actual problem?

Comment: @ElectricLlama The image is just to show what I want to do. I just need a code sample on how to add multiple items to a container.

Comment: @billinkc this is 2008 R2

Comment: Sorry... I missed the EzAPI bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can really be distilled down to two questions: How do I create the various Containers and Tasks? How do I define precedence constraints between them?

As you can see in the code below, I create instances of the `EzPackage`, `EzForEachLoop`, `EzExecSqlTask` and `EzDataFlowTask`. EzAPI tasks and containers all accept a parent object in their constructor. This is how you specify what scope an object should exist at. Thus, the For Each Loop takes the base package as its argument but the Data Flow and Execute SQL Task use the For Each Loop so that they are created inside that container.

There are different mechanisms for defining the Precedence Constraint between objects and it's up to you which version you use: object.AttachTo vs package.PrecedenceConstraints.Add

```
    public static void GimmieDaCodez()
    {
        EzPackage ezPackage = null;
        EzForEachLoop ezLoop = null;
        string packageName = @"so_22533130";
        string outputFile = string.Format("{0}.dtsx",System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Dropbox\Sandbox\UtumnoSandbox\EzAPIDemo\EzAPIDemo", packageName));

        EzDataFlow df1 = null;
        EzDataFlow df2 = null;
        EzDataFlow df3 = null;
        EzExecSqlTask t4 = null;


        // Instantiate and configure our package
        ezPackage = new EzPackage();
        ezPackage.Name = packageName;
        ezPackage.Description = "A package with a foreach enumerator and muliple data flows";

        // Lazy initialization of FELC
        ezLoop = new EzForEachLoop(ezPackage);
        ezLoop.Name = "FELC Enumerate stuff";
        ezLoop.Description = "EzAPI still does not allow configuration of FELC beyond file enumerator";

        // Instantiate our tasks. Details left to the implementer
        df1 = new EzDataFlow(ezLoop);
        df1.Name = "DFT 1";
        df2 = new EzDataFlow(ezLoop);
        df2.Name = "DFT 2";
        df3 = new EzDataFlow(ezLoop);
        df3.Name = "DFT 3";
        t4 = new EzExecSqlTask(ezLoop);
        t4.Name = "SQL Do all the things";

        df2.AttachTo(df1);
        df3.AttachTo(df1);
        t4.AttachTo(df2);
        t4.AttachTo(df3);

        ezPackage.SaveToFile(outputFile);
    }
```

Using that code, I generate a package that looks like

[image]

### References

- My [EzAPI posts](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/search/label/EzAPI)
- [SSIS Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api.aspx)
- [EzAPI project subsite](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21238)

Comment: Just want to know, whether we can have multiple data flow task inside a Foreach Loop Container. My Source file is an excel file which has 8 sheets.Each Data Flow Task is connected to each  Excel File & their corresponding Sheet.